# How do you substitute the values of sympy.core.add.add objects when they are in a list?

Tags: python, loops, sympy

I have a list of sympy objects that I would like to evaluate at a certain point (x0 = 1 , x1=1), I have tried using evalf and subs in a **for** loop but have had no luck. Here is my code:

```
from sympy import *
b = [3*x0**2 + 4*x1, 4*x0]
for i in b:
    i = i.subs({x0:1, x1:1})
print(b)
```

It returns the same list as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you're not operating on `b` at all.

You could do this.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x0 x1')
(x0, x1)
>>> b = [3*x0**2 + 4*x1, 4*x0]
>>> [_.subs({x0:1, x1:1}) for _ in b]
[7, 4]
```

Notice that this code operates on each expression within `b` individually because `b` as a whole is not a sympy expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I had not realised that I was not replacing the elements of b in my loop. I still have a problem though, because I would like to do the same for an n*n numpy matrix but I am not sure how to go about that

Comment: Time to post another question!